# GStreamer multi pipeline time sync

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I work on an application which consist of multiple pipelines:

- Video source: capture video, do some simple operation on it (encode and overlaying) and passing the output to an appsink
- Audio source: capture audio and forward it to an appsink
- Streamer: sending the video (and maybe later audio as well) over as UDP stream or WebRTC (live video)
- Buffer: a plain c++ class which stores the buffers for a configured time (it can be changed dynamically, and the audio and video buffer time can be different, so it should be possible that the video starts a few minutes before from the buffer before the audio)
- Filewriter: this is a simple filesink, when its triggered I push the buffers to it's audio and video appsrc with the gst_app_src_push_buffer methond (at the moment I encode the video with VP8 to a webm file using a webmmux).

All of pipelines are started at the same time (sequentially after each other).

```
VideoSource ----------------->    LiveStream
            |
            \
               -------------->                     record trigger
                                  Buffer---------------- X ---------------->    FileWriter
AudioSource ----------------->
```

I have two kinds of issues:

- I cannot make the audio and video sync in the filewriter
- During playback the playtime counter not starts from 0 (I think it is somehow receiving the timestamp from the Video source, so when I start the video in VLC it start countig from eg.: 30 seconds which is the amount of time I waited until I triggered the record) and Im not able seek in the video file.

I tried to play around with following approaches:

- the 'do-timestamp' and 'is-live' properties on the filewriter's receiving appsrc
- reset the timestamps on the buffers (audio and video) with 'GST_BUFFER_PTS' to a sequentially value starting from zero and  increased with the duration
- adjust the timestamps on the buffers (audio and video) with 'GST_BUFFER_PTS' with the time difference between the start times of the source and filewriter timelines
- tried to sync all piplines by setting the same clock on them and use the same basetime on them

I think I miss some fundamental thing here. Can you give me some hints how should I properly do this time synchronisation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could it be that timestamps are created incorrectly? Maybe try to use `videorate` after `videosrc`?